# DragDrop disables MouseMove Event?

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, controls, mousemove

I'm having trouble while making a custom control in which users can drag ListviewItems.
I want to give the user some graphical feedback as for where the dropped items will go, but the MouseMove event does not fire when drag & dropping.

Is there anything I can do except for starting/stopping a timer on `onDragEnter` and `onDragLeave` ?

[image: The control users can drag tracks into]
This is the control I'm talking about, this should make my idea pretty clear.

Comment: Is this custom control inherited from a ListView? Are you dragging and dropping within the same control?

Comment: No this custom control is inherited from `Control`. I'm dragging items from a listview (tracks) to the custom control (into the playlists).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used something like this before in the DragOver event handler of ListBox:

```
Dim intIndex As Integer
intIndex = ListBox1.IndexFromPoint(ListBox1.PointToClient(New Point(e.X, e.Y)))
ListBox1.SelectedIndex = intIndex
```

Maybe it's possible you could do something similar with your custom control.  Sorry this is in VB not C#, but I imagine it wouldn't be too hard to translate.

Comment: This would modify the current selection; not sure that's what the OP had in mind, but perhaps. Aside from being an answer in VB for C#, it's also using ListBox and not ListView, and SelectedIndex isn't a member of ListView. SelectedIndices is, since the ListView is multi-select and the ListBox is single, by default. Need more info from the OP.

Comment: I did not realize that the `DragOver` event _does_ fire when the mouse moves over the control. I now make a call to the `onMouseMove` Method inside the `onDragOver` Event and that seems to be working fine. Thanks!